Can we use connection pooling with Asp Identity context? Will there be any impact on cached data in UserManager or RoleManager?
Can we use connection pooling with Asp Identity context? Will there be any impact on cached data in UserManager or RoleManager? I found AspIdentity context used AddDbContext method and creating high CPU usage. Just wanted to make sure the changing from AddDbContext to AddDbContextPool does'nt break the identity code.
